# How do you set the path in a non-shell environment (KDE)?

Tags: kde, path

I'd like to override one of the applications set in `/usr/bin/`. I have created an alternative with the same name in `~/bin/` which in in my `PATH` (as set both in `.bashrc` and in `.profile`).

When I start the application from the console, I get the expected result: my application is started instead of one from the distribution.

However, within KDE, when I do alt+F2 and type in the application name, the one in `/usr/bin` starts instead of the one in `~/bin/`.

How do I set KDE so that `~/bin` is recognized from everywhere in KDE.

I'll probably also have to edit the K-menu, although I am not sure how to do it with KDE4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thirs hit in google for 'KDE environment variables' is [this](http://userbase.kde.org/Session_Environment_Variables) which seems to be what you're looking for.

(You can also configure the login manager to export a specific $PATH - the man page for xdm illustrates how to do this)

Answer (score 6):

On my system there is a directory

```
$HOME/.kde/env
```

All the scripts that directory that end in .sh are executed. I for instance have a script there called profile.sh that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LC_TIME=en_DK.utf8  # ISO 8601 dates
[ "$LC_ALL" != "$LC_TIME" ] && unset LC_ALL
```

to make sure that Firefox and Thunderbird use international standards for date and time.