# Transparently run wine programs

Tags: command-line, wine, dwm, dmenu

When I want to run a wine program I have to type e.g.

`$ wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/TextAloud/TextAloudMP3.exe`

Would it be possible to run directly `TextAloudMP3`? I mean not only from command line (I could create alias) but in whole graphical environment. I'm launching programs with [`dmenu`](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/).

Answer (score 10):

I guess you meant to launch exe programs with wine directly, so tell kernel to run win32 binaries with wine by,

1. Mount binfmt fs, add a line `none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc defaults 0 0` to /etc/fstab and execute `mount -a` afterwards
2. `echo ':DOSWin:M::MZ::/usr/bin/wine:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register` to register the binary format

So later, you just run the exe file with `/path/to/XX.exe`

Note that this also introduces a security problem.

Comment: I can't edit `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register`. It writes `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register E667: Fsync failed`. I tried to edit under user acount with `sudo` and under root account too. Both write this error.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know the kernel could do that. This particular use case feels evil though. But I like that even when opening _that_ door,  filenames, that is extensions, do not matter, whereas other OSes ... :D

Comment: @xralf: How are you trying to edit the file?  echo should work, but some (most/all?) editors may not work, because it's not a real editable file, it's virtual within the proc filesystem.

Comment: @xralf don't edit with vim

Comment: @warl0ck I have to do it under `root` account. I added `/path/to/` to my `$PATH` variable and I can run `XX.exe` from command line but still can't run it from `dmenu`. Sorry I've mistaken it with `xmobar` in the question.

Comment: On Fedora, installing `wine-systemd` adds `/usr/lib/binfmt.d/wine.conf`, which is run by `systemd-binfmt.service` at boot time---and that does the registration so you don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `wine` is [in your path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) and create a shell script containing the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
wine "$HOME/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/TextAloud/TextAloudMP3.exe"
```

Give yourself permission to execute the script by running `chmod u+x SCRIPT_NAME`.

Then, just run that script from your file manager. It will start wine, which will run TextAloudMP3.exe.

Comment: I created a script named `textaloud` in `/usr/local/bin` folder. First line is `#! /bin/bash` second line is `wine ...`. textaloud won't appear in `xmobar` launcher. When running `sh textaloud` it writes `$ sh textaloud
wine: cannot find '~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/TextAloud/TextAloudMP3.exe'`

Comment: Oops. `~` doesn't expand to a user's home directory when it's within double quotation marks. I have modified my answer to use the environmental variable `$HOME` instead.

Comment: `sh textaloud` already works, but only from the directory `/usr/local/bin` and it's still not visible in xmobar launcher.

Comment: might want to add `$@` after the program name so it passes all arguments. And I usually put such scripts in ~/bin (after making sure it is in your PATH, of course).

Comment: Couldn't you also define an alias in `~/.bash_aliases`?

Answer (score 3):

### Step 0

Set a binary PATH for your user. Run `mkdir ~/bin` and add this directory to your PATH.

How this is done may vary depending on the shell and desktop environment you use.

[Here you can found how to change your PATH in a variety of shells](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-adding-path/).

[Check this solved question if your desktop environment don't care about your shell profile and the former does work from the terminal but not from the desktop environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-you-set-the-path-in-a-non-shell-environment-kde).

### Step 1

Once you have set your shell and your desktop environment to respect a new PATH, you can drop scripts there and run them as regular commands without typing their path.

Create a short shell script to run your wine program in this directory, i.e. `~/bin/textaloud`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "~/.wine/drive_c"
exec wine "~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/TextAloud/TextAloudMP3.exe" "$@"
```

And give it execute permission.

```
chmod +x ~/bin/textaloud
```

There are three things to note about the above script:

- The `cd` path is where the program is going to be run (in which directory). Some programs may require you to run them on a specific directory. If you have trouble with this, set there that directory (usually the same where the executable is located). You may unwant this line in some cases.
- The `exec` commands tell bash to morph into wine with the following arguments, so this is no longer bash running wine, but bash process becoming wine. The PID remains. You don't have two processes running.
- The `$@` is substituted with the arguments you ran the script, if any. So those are passed to your wine program.

Now you can run your program from the shell like...

```
textaloud
```

### Step 2

Create an application launcher. Nowadays these files are standarized as `.desktop` files and many desktop environments provide graphical tools to create them.

Here is an example skeleton you can use to write it yourself. You may want to provide an icon (often in PNG, SVG or XPM).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=TextAloud
Exec=textaloud
Icon=textaloud.png
```

Place this file in `~/.local/share/applications/TextAloud.desktop`. Icons are searched (among other places) in `~/.local/share/icons`, so make sure to find a cute icon for your application and place it there with the name `textaloud.png`.

Once you had done this, your desktop environment should find your shortcut file and be able to run the program with the script. If not, reload or restart it.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your guide but the last step don't work. I can't see `textaloud` in `dmenu` launcher.

Comment: The step 2 is directed to desktops like GNOME, KDE or XFCE. dmenu does not seem to care about .desktop files, so with Step 1 you should be fine. Did it work from the terminal? If it did but still does not work, review Step 0. Maybe you are using `~/.xsession` to get your X11 sesion? Try adding there `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` before the line you use to run dwm and restart X11.

Comment: In works from terminal without problems. PATH is OK. Only the question to be complete I'd like to work it from dmenu.

Comment: I told you. Do you have `~/.xsession`? Be aware the PATH of your terminal may not be equal to the PATH of your X11 session.

Comment: `$@` should be in double quotes for safety. so it would become `exec wine "~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/TextAloud/TextAloudMP3.exe" "$@"`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying PlayOnLinux? It can take care of the whole thing for you and even you can configure some filetypes to be opened by wine programs.