# Can a Windows executable file be searched in $PATH, when running it under wine?

Tags: path, wine

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/t/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

$ which PDFXCview.exe
/home/t/bin//PDFXCview.exe

$ ls /home/t/bin/PDFXCview.exe  -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 t t 97 Mar 18 09:20 /home/t/bin/PDFXCview.exe -> ../program_files/document/formats/pdf/TrackerSoftware/pdfxcview/pdfxchange_portable/PDFXCview.exe
```

Now,

```
$ wine /home/t/bin/PDFXCview.exe   &
[1] 23220
```

But even though `PDFXCview.exe` is searcheable in `$PATH`,

```
$ wine PDFXCview.exe
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\PDFXCview.exe"
```

Is the failure because that `PDFXCview.exe` does not appear as a command name in `wine PDFXCview.exe`, so it is not searched in `$PATH`?

Is there some way to make `PDFXCview.exe`  in `wine PDFXCview.exe` searched in `$PATH`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to make Wine programs available from a path.

1. You can make the Windows program executable, and add its containing directory to your PATH; see [Transparently run wine programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70681/86440) and [How is Mono magical?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259376/86440) for details. You’d then run

   ```
   PDFXCview.exe
   ```

   to start the program.
2. You can add the Wine directory containing the executable to the Wine path. To do this, [run `wine regedit`](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Setting_Windows.2FDOS_environment_variables), find the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment` entry, and edit the `Path` value (using `;` to separate directories). You can use `winepath` to convert Linux paths to Wine paths. You’d then run

   ```
   wine PDFXCview
   ```

   to start the program.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a good idea to put `alias PDFXCview="wine /home/t/bin/PDFXCview.exe"` in `~/.profile`?

Comment: Yes, that works too ([in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` rather than `.profile` though](https://superuser.com/a/183980/414739)). The difference is that you need one alias per program, instead of one path entry per directory containing programs you want to run.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Why define environment variables in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, and alias and functions in `~/.bashrc`? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/431832/674 (2)  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76641/674 suggests to write a shell script for each .exe file, so it is still done per program, just as alias is, isn't it?